# How to check list of supported codecs with cmd?

Tags: ffmpeg, cmd.exe, video-codecs

I would like to know how to check list of supported or installed codecs on Windows 10 using command line. I did it on ubuntu with `ffmpeg -codecs`. I don't want to use GUI to know that.

Comment: What problem do you have using the very same `ffmpeg -codecs` in cmd?

Comment: command not found.

Comment: Then install the windows version of ffmpeg, it is not installed by default.

Comment: Is there any way know that without installing any additional software?

Comment: You could use powershell `Get-WmiObject win32_codecfile` but the information provided by ffmpeg is much more detailed.

Comment: FYI: `ffmpeg -codecs` will provide a list that ffmpeg can process, not the list of codecs available on your system for playback using Directshow.

Comment: Thank you all. That's information I was looking for

Comment: Please answer your own question using the button below. Or @LotPings, do you want to answer the post?